# with using a timefilter, i get the following error: '}' - not all control paths return a value

Tags: mql4, mql5

I get the error: '}' - not all control paths return a value.
I am using:

```
 int StartHour = 8;
 int EndHour = 20;
```

And this is the code I am using:

```
bool TimeFilter()
    {
    EndHour1=EndHour+GMTOffset;
    StartHour1=StartHour+GMTOffset;
    if ((StartHour+GMTOffset)<0)  {StartHour1=StartHour+GMTOffset+24;} 
    if ((EndHour+GMTOffset)<0)    {EndHour1=EndHour+GMTOffset+24;}     
    if ((StartHour+GMTOffset)>24) {StartHour1=StartHour+GMTOffset-24;} 
    if ((EndHour+GMTOffset)>24)   {EndHour1=EndHour+GMTOffset-24;}    
    

if (Use_TimeFilter==false) {comment1=""; return (true);}
      else 

if (StartHour1<EndHour1)
       {
         if (Hour()>=StartHour1 && Hour()<EndHour1)
         {
         comment1=""; 
         return (true);
         } 
         
         comment1="WARNING: Trading diluar Time Filter, No Open Position\n"; 
         return (false);
       }
 
     else
     
if (StartHour1>EndHour1)

       {
         if (Hour()>=StartHour1 || Hour()<EndHour1)
         {
         comment1=""; 
         return (true);
         } 
         comment1="WARNING: Trading diluar Time Filter, No Open Position\n"; 
         return (false);
       }

}
```

What is wrong and how to fix this so i don't receive this error anymore.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using multiple nested `if` `else` statements and there exists a possible scenario which would result in all the `if` statements not being fulfilled (ie `Use_TimeFilter=True` and `StartHour1==EndHour1`). You therefore need to simply add a final `return(false)` statement in your code.

```
bool TimeFilter()
{
   EndHour1=EndHour+GMTOffset;
   StartHour1=StartHour+GMTOffset;
   if((StartHour+GMTOffset)<0)  {StartHour1=StartHour+GMTOffset+24;} 
   if((EndHour+GMTOffset)<0)    {EndHour1=EndHour+GMTOffset+24;}     
   if((StartHour+GMTOffset)>24) {StartHour1=StartHour+GMTOffset-24;} 
   if((EndHour+GMTOffset)>24)   {EndHour1=EndHour+GMTOffset-24;}    

   if(!Use_TimeFilter) {comment1=""; return (true);}
   else if(StartHour1<EndHour1)
   {
      if(Hour()>=StartHour1 && Hour()<EndHour1)
      {
         comment1=""; 
      return(true);
      }
      comment1="WARNING: Trading diluar Time Filter, No Open Position\n"; 
   return(false);
   }
   else if(StartHour1>EndHour1)
   {
      if (Hour()>=StartHour1 || Hour()<EndHour1)
      {
         comment1=""; 
      return (true);
      } 
      comment1="WARNING: Trading diluar Time Filter, No Open Position\n"; 
   return (false);
   }
return(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it.
And thanks for the explanation, it does makes sense what you say.